# Message at startup: "ata3.15: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6"

Tags: hard-drive

```
ata3.15: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6
```

This message shows up when the OS starts.

How can I find out what ata4 means? Which hard drive does it refer to?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. One easy way is to check the boot messages:

```
dmesg | grep ata4
```

One of the output lines should list the name of the device. In my case,

```
$ dmesg | grep ata1
[    0.661885] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m131072@0xfcc80000 port 0xfcc80100 irq 39
[    1.136128] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.137690] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.138275] ata1.00: disabling queued TRIM support
[    1.138277] ata1.00: ATA-9: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB, EMT02B6Q, max UDMA/133
[    1.138279] ata1.00: 488397168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    1.139271] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.139809] ata1.00: disabling queued TRIM support
[    1.140580] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

This tells me it's a Samsung 850 EVO 250GB.

`ata4` corresponds to `/dev/sdd` -- the *d* being the 4th *S*ata *D*isk.

It should also correspond to SATA connector 4 on your motherboard.